# Combine two default Ansible host files including one being ec2.py?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I'm using Ansible is a mixed environment of AWS and non-AWS machines.  I'd like to avoid passing hosts on the command line.  How do I combine multiple host files in Ansible and make it the default?  The current recommendation on the Ansible site is to override /etc/ansible/hosts with ec2.py. which prevents me from adding additional hosts. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can mix dynamic and static inventory files by creating a directory and dropping ec2.py in it plus your ini formatted inventory list as a separate file.
It is mentioned briefly in the docs [here](http://docs.ansible.com/intro_inventory.html#splitting-out-host-and-group-specific-data).

```
for example:

  ./inventory/ec2.py
  ./inventory/additional-hosts

  ansible-playbook ... -i inventory/
```

Note that any file with the executable bit set will be treated as a dynamic inventory so make sure you files have the correct permissions.